# Find $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=x^3\cdot\ln (x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=x^3\cdot\ln (x)$

My Attempt:
$$y=x^3\cdot\ln (x)$$
Differentiating $n$ times using Leibniz' Theorem,
$$y_{n}=\dfrac {(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!}{x^{n-3}}
+n\cdot\dfrac {(-1)^{n-2} (n-2)!}{x^{n-1}}\cdot3x^2\\
+ \dfrac {n(n-1)}{2!}\times \dfrac {(-1)^{n-3} (n-3)!}{x^{n-2}}\cdot 6x\\
+\dfrac {n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\times \dfrac {(-1)^{n-4} (n-4)!}{x^{n-3}}\cdot6
$$

Comment: I've changed all $.$ to $\cdot$ (\cdot), but you better be consistent with the usage of $\cdot$ and $\times$.

Comment: It may be helpful to write out the first several derivatives and look for a pattern.

Comment: With CAS: $\frac{\partial ^n\left(x^3 \ln (x)\right)}{\partial x^n}=\frac{x^{3-n} \left(11-6
   H_{3-n}+6 \ln (x)\right)}{\Gamma (4-n)}$ where: $H$ is harmonic number.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$y'=3x^2\log x+x^2\;,\;\;y''=6x\log x+5x\;,\;\;y'''=6\log x+11\;,\ldots$$

Sometimes doing a few first derivatives helps way more than Leibniz Theorem

Comment: I couldn't figure out the general expression for $n^{th}$ order derivative.

Comment: @pi-π Can you give the general expression for the $\;n\,-$th derivative of $\;\log x\;$ ? Because that's almost exactly what you're left with beginning at the $\;4\,-$th derivative...

Comment: For $y=\ln (x)$ its $y_n=(-1)^{n-1} \dfrac {(n-1)!}{x^n}$.

Comment: @pi-π, and there you go, you then know that $(y''')^{(n)} = 6(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{x^n}$.

Comment: @pi-π Exactly...